# Wordpress header and search engine optimization issue

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I would like to optimize the header of my wordpress website-blog. By default I see only these entries:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Well, I would like to add a description tag, keywords and facebook Open Graph. But as I do, when sharing a blog post on facebook, the post description gets overwrited and this is not what I want.

How could I have a default description tag for my business, but keep the blog post description as well in case I am sharing some content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-meta-tags/

It seems to accept site-wide meta tags as well as content-related ones.

Comment: Thanks @3840 - It could work, but I am not a big fan of wp plugins. I would prefer to write it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will rewrite those descriptions, not Wordpress.
You have to add another meta tags for Facebook, called Open Graph tags, such as og:title, og:description and others.